# Why Bigquery cancel my job with the message: User requested cancellation

Tags: google-bigquery

I'm running a complex query using BigQuery which typically takes around 10 to 15 minutes.

From time to time I get this error message after a few minutes

> },
>         "errors": [
>           {
>             "reason": "stopped",
>             "message": "Job execution was cancelled: User requested cancellation"
>           }
>         ]

My Problem: **I never** really cancelled the job

Note: My company use Slots plan

While comparing the 2 execution plans I see in the done job `queryPlan` this:

```
{
            "elapsedMs": "925059",
            "totalSlotMs": "1953194186",
            "pendingUnits": "10",
            "completedUnits": "9552824",
            "activeUnits": "34"
          },
          {
            "elapsedMs": "929846",
            "totalSlotMs": "1953359349",
            "pendingUnits": "0",
            "completedUnits": "9553245",
            "activeUnits": "52"
          },
          {
            "elapsedMs": "933051",
            "totalSlotMs": "1953359385",
            *"pendingUnits": "0",*
            "completedUnits": "9553247",
            "activeUnits": "0"
          }
```

And in the failed job this:

```
{
            "elapsedMs": "725882",
            "totalSlotMs": "2225404959",
            "pendingUnits": "4219883",
            "completedUnits": "5330112",
            "activeUnits": "16062"
          },
          {
            "elapsedMs": "729400",
            "totalSlotMs": "2254808579",
            *"pendingUnits": "4215314",*
            "completedUnits": "5334681",
            "activeUnits": "15423"
          }
```

As if for some reason BigQuery stopped allocating units and following this I got the above error message.

Any idea what can cause such an issue?

Comment: Please file an issue on the issue tracker with a job id

Answer (score 0):

The reason for this is a slot limit defined by the IT to prevent queries coming from API not to exceed specific limit